# SSRS: If two parties are the same name in the fullname field, how do I parse 1 record of info?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

Hoping to get some help on this issue I've been tackling.

Here is a given scenario.  AgentName can have two types. LB or SB.

If AgentName is the same for both LB and SB in a file, I would like to just return SB records.

I'm grouping the SSRS Reports by AgentName. and below is the parsed result as of now:
[image: parsed]

**So ideally,I'd like to add a condition that is:
 if an AgentName is the same on the same Order No, then parse Agent SB record information.** (refer to the screenshot above)

Below is my sample code:

```
    Select distinct an.fullname, a.code, a.companycode, a.co, an.title, an.phone, an.email, o.orderno, o.closedate

from db.order o 
 left outer join db.contact a on (o.rootid=a.id)
 left outer join db.person an on (o.rootid=an.id and ab.id between a.id and a.lastid and an.ismainperson=1)

where a.code in ('LB','SB')
```

Comment: You'll probably need to edit your question to show a sample of your data in the order, contact and person tables. I think the solution will be simple in T-SQL once we know the structure.

Comment: This is usually achieved by using RANK() to assign a number to each record and only picking record number 1. Are you on a version of SQL Server that supports `RANK()`?

Comment: Yes I am. I've never used RANK() before. I will look further into it